# Docker compose multiple FROM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-mac

I'm using macOS on the client and Ubuntu 16.04 on the server side.

I want to ask that if I define a docker-compose.yml file like below:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    server:
      image: ubuntu
    web:
      image: nginx
    php:
      image: 7.1.12-fpm-alpine
```

Does it install ubuntu, debian (FROM debian:stretch-slim) and alpine?

or just install ubuntu, nginx and php-7-fpm?

What should I do if I want to second one?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  You're defining three different containers, each from a different image.

Comment: I just want to host a custom homemade php application that use ubuntu, nginx, mariadb, php7, composer and git

Comment: Try it and see. This type of question does not belong on SO. Also - in your compose, you're only referencing the tag and not the image, it should be `image: php:7.1.12-fpm-alpine`

Comment: To answer your question though; it will bring up a single ubuntu, single nginx, and single PHP container. If you want more than one, look into the `replicas` option in the docker-compose file documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused with docker-compose and Dockerfile files.

Docker-compose is for composing different applications (containers defined by images) to work together. E.g. if you have a PHP web application which uses a database, you would define a service for the database and a service for the web application. What you are doing (or trying to do) here is defining 3 different container. This is probably not what you want to do.

Dockerfile is to build a custom application image. It's like the recipe for your application. You probably want something like that. Just use a php image as "FROM" (base image) and add your custom application to the image. The documentations of the images usually state how to do that - check it on Docker hub!